# Suitable FFC socket for this LCD module

Tags: connector, lcd, pcb-assembly, mechanical-assembly, ffc

I've ordered [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/snapshot/6449437156.html?orderId=65441718045819) LCD module, and I'm trying to find a suitable connector for it. It's 26 pins with pitch of 0.8mm, but as you can see, the right hand side is "sticking out" of the connector. Is this module compatible with the standard FFC 26 pins socket?

[image: The LCD module with it's flex cable]

Comment: Are you sure that the contact spacing is 8mm? Seems much more likely that this would be 0.8mm although it is far more common spacing for such tab would be 1.0mm.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Yes. I measured it myself. These are not nearly as common as 1mm+ or 0.5mm, but they do exist.

Comment: @MichaelKaras OOPS! I meant 0.8mm. Question fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that you would find a standard connector that could accomodate the flex tab off this display directly. All the connectors I've seen have side to side openings that correctly align the tab with the connector so that the contacts line up.

If your project is a one off type of thing you may be able to follow one of two approaches.

1. Cut away part of the flex tab on the overhang side so that it fits correctly in a standard connector.
2. You may be able to find certain connectors that could live through you grinding out one edge making the connector with an open throat on one side. For this I would select a connector that was a hard body instead of a soft nylon style.

Another alternative that you have is to see if a wider connector such as a 30 pin unit has a throat wide enough for this whole tab to fit into. You would just skip connecting to the pins of the connector where the overhang on the tab exists. My analysis shows that a 30pin connector would work in this manner.

[image]

Since you are looking at low cost displays from AliExpress you could look at adding these 0.8mm 30 contact FFC connectors into the cart. The each price for the connectors is pretty low.

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Fpc-ffc-connector-socket-flat-flexible-cable-socket-0-8mm-30p-socket/1255563803.html

Comment: Interesting. What do you think the original intention was with this module? Did they have a custom connector? Soldered it directly to the board?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to struggle here.  Michael is correct, it's likely to be 0.8mm pitch or similar fine pitch (0.5 or 1.00mm), however from a connector point of view the issue is that the FPC contact section is not square, it has the additional area.  Generally FFC connectors have a closed end at each side and fit perfectly with FFC or FPC in a suitable thickness and a specific number of contacts.

So for example, you might have 26 contacts and you would find a 26 contact connector of the correct pitch, orientation (straight or right angle) and accepting the appropriate FFC/FPC thickness.  However, to my knowledge connectors will only accept 26 contacts as they have fixed sidewalls and will not accept the extra dimension that the piece of FPC adds on one side.

FYI only [Digi Key list 66 0.8mm pitch connectors](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en?pv89=109&FV=fff40016%2Cfff80421&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) but you can see it's not a popular range and not stocked.  As a point of reference Digi Key have over 11,000 FFC connector choices.

Comment: That was a typo, I meant 0.8mm. So I guess I'm better off selecting a different, standard LCD module. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, unless anyone has a bright idea on a connector solution.